# How to create a To Do List App with Fragment View Pager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Am trying to create an To-Do List Android App where on the Main Activity;

- The user clicks on a Floating Action Button that then launches a new Activity.
- From this Activity the user enters a new Task in an Edit Text then clicks 
  on a Button to create the task.
- This then creates a New Task with a Check Box on the Main Activity that 
  contains a Fragment View Pager for completed Tasks and Not Done Task.

Issue is am trying to figure out how to code this but still haven't gotten enough info online on how to go about it. Am relatively new to Android so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: don't put your assignment here, atleast try to make basic activity and do some research for android coding..if still you face issues then post it.

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/starting-android-development-creating-todo-app/ Easy and clear.

Comment: @PrachiSingh Already did some research and couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Do some more research and then ask questions on StackOverflow. People here are professional people who try and give some of their valuable time to solve any ERRORS fellow programmers might face, they aren't here to Google stuff for you that you couldn't on your own. @PrachiSingh is right. Research  before you ask question.

Comment: You can find a tutorial as @MarkWalczak linked. There are many kind of tutorials that you can learn how to do it. First, you need to understand how fragments and databases work. Tutorials may help you about it. You can get some benefit taking note apps. Because it's similar with todo list.